# Setting a weak ivar and getting nil

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, automatic-ref-counting

In an ARC project, I'm setting a __weak ivar (declared as `id __weak weakLayer;`) to a CALayer which is retained by it's superlayer. Most times this works. Sometimes, the weak ivar tests as nil. I wrote some test code to simplify debugging that demonstrates the problem. I expect this to be an infinite loop but it breaks out, usually in less than 20 iterations. The number of iterations required to break out is not consistent.

```
array = [NSMutableArray array];
while (1) {
  CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
  [array addObject:layer];
  weakLayer = layer;
  if (!weakLayer) {
    NSLog (@"nil");
    break;
  }
  NSLog(@"not nil");
}
```

If I drop a breakpoint with an action of `po weakLayer` inside the `if`, it prints a valid object. I have tested on Xcode 4.3.3 and 4.4 with the Lion and Mountain Lion SDKs.

Comment: Is this the actual code you're testing or a mock version?

Comment: It's the actual code lifted from a test project.

Comment: I made a sample project, but can’t reproduce it: https://github.com/DouglasHeriot/WeakIvarTest Is there anything you’re doing differently?

Comment: @DouglasHeriot Are you running on 10.8? I'm still on 10.7.4.

Comment: Yes, I’m on 10.8, using 10.8 SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 people (including myself) have now confirmed this to work on 10.8, but not on 10.7.4.